# Probability of discrete-random process

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable

If $N_{\tau}$ is random process of number of items sold in $\tau$ minutes by probability below

$$
\begin{align*}
P_{N\tau}(n)=(5\tau)^n  e^{-5τ}/n!
\end{align*}
$$
for $n=0,1,2,...$

Then imagine you wait a random time of $W$ minutes until you see an item is sold. What is the distribution of W?

I know that it asks for $P[W>w]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- $P[W>w] = P[N_w=0] = P_{N_w}(0)$
- So you can find $P[W\le w]$ as a cumulative distribution function
- and its derivative as a probability density function

In fact this is a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) with a rate of $5$ per minute.  $W$ has an exponential distribution with the same rate